# Convert Byte array into collection of items of different types

Tags: c#

I'm recieving UDP messages as byte arrays and depending on details in some of the first byte, I need to convert remaining bytes into a multitude of different possible arrangements of other data types.

These data types are primarily 'uint', 'ushort' and just 'byte' but can be in any order, and there can be any number of them. Each of these items will have a named variable.

I've tried using quite a few different options and am getting close, but feel that the methods I've created are not the best they could be. In places I've wanted to use 'sizeof' but don't want to mark the code as 'unsafe'. I've tried to use the 'params' keyword on the input, but this cannot be in conjunction with 'ref'. I've wanted to pass them with a maximum number of T1, T2, etc. using generics, but realised I can't enumerate these. I'm now passing an array of variables in conjunction with the 'ref' keyword, which means creating the array in memory but only the array gets updated with the changed and not the original variables.

```
byte[] message = new byte[] { }; //some byte array
ushort item1 = default(ushort);
byte item2 = default(byte);
var argumentArray = new object[] { item1, item2 };
ConvertArray(response, ref argumentArray);
```

```
private void ConvertArray(byte[] response, ref object[] items)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        var item = items[i];
        var itemType = item.GetType();
        var itemSize = SizeOf(item.GetType());

        if (itemSize == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (itemSize == 1)
        {
            items[i] = response[index];
        }
        else
        {
            var method = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod($"To{itemType.Name}");
            var returned = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { response, index });
            items[i] = Convert.ChangeType(returned, itemType);
        }

        index = index + itemSize;
     }
}
```

```
private int SizeOf(Type type)
{
   switch (type.Name)
   {
       case nameof(UInt16):
           return 2;

       case "Byte":
           return 1;

       default:
           return 0;
   }
}
```

So this is partially working in that 'argumentArray' is updating with the values from the 'ConvertArray' method, but I'm sure there is a neater way to do this using Types.

Ideally I wouldn't need to create the 'argumentArray' and just pass the items (e.g. Item1 and Item2) directly as arguments to the method.

Comment: I would consider writing a streamreader/writer pair for problems like this. You could write a parser on top of the reader.

Comment: What does _this is partially working_ mean?

Comment: Question number two, why do you need `ref` there? You're not re-assigning `items` it...

Comment: @t3chb0t I've edited to reassign, and changed to dynamic instead of objects so that I don't need to cast the array elements. It would be a lot neater to not have to assign the array elements back to the variables though. It would be ideal if I could use 'ref' with 'params'.

Comment: Firstly, you must not change the code after answers have been posted so I reverted the edit... secondly, the edit still doesn't make sense and does not use `ref`. I don't think you know how `ref` works...

Comment: @t3chb0t when you reverted my question, it rendered your comment useless as no-one could see the edit. I know how ref works, and if you're going to just be rude I'd rather you didn't comment.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers): _**Do not add an improved version of the code** after receiving an answer. Including revised versions of the code makes the question confusing, especially if someone later reviews the newer code._ Please refrain from further code edits.

Comment: FWIW [everyone can see the edits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/220831/revisions)

Comment: @sebpinski can you clarify _why_ you need `ref`? As t3chb0t, I'm inclined to believe you have misunderstood how it works; my first suggestion would be to remove it, as it may create confusion. Your code will behave exactly the same without it (assuming the caller does not change `items` concurrently, which is presumably not a supported use-case).

Comment: @VisualMelon Agreed that 'ref' is not needed in this instance, but I'm wanting to be able to pass the value types as the arguments which are the intended destination of the extracted data, hence the expectation to need to pass those arguments by reference.

Comment: @sebpinski OK; however, that won't work. The array of objects does not contain references, `ref` just means you pass the array itself by reference. The only want to pass an array of references to value-typed variables like that in C# is with pointers, (or you could use closures).

Comment: @VisualMelon Yes, aware of that, and in the now reverted edit I included assigning the individual returned array elements back to the original value type variables. Using pointers, I'll need to mark the code as 'unsafe' and I won't be allowed to use the 'params' keyword, or 'object*[]' in the call signature or even add the pointers to an 'object' array.

Comment: @sebpinski our confusion, is that you don't need `ref` for the reverted code to work either. Simply, the `ConvertArray` method does not change `items` (that is, whereto the reference points), so the only semantic difference is that `items` could be changed by another thread while this code is running, so it seems the `ref` is achieving nothing.

Comment: @VisualMelon did I not just say that I agreed with you?

Comment: @VisualMelon The ref is just there are the aftermath of trying to pass the value types directly before realising 'ref' was not compatible with the 'params' keyword, I just neglected to remove it once changing to passing the array.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the implication in your previous comment. I was just confused, because you suggested that you made a decision to not use `params` because it is incompatible with `ref`, but there doesn't seem to be any reason to use `ref`.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>        case nameof(UInt16):
>            return 2;
>
>        case "Byte":
>            return 1;
> ```

Be consistent. `nameof` is clearly preferable.

---

> ```
> private void ConvertArray(byte[] response, ref object[] items)
> {
>     int index = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
>     {
>         var item = items[i];
>         var itemType = item.GetType();
>         var itemSize = SizeOf(item.GetType());
> ```

1. The last line should use the variable `itemType`.
2. The sole point of `items` seems to be to extract types. So why is the parameter not `params Type[] types`?

---

> ```
>         if (itemSize == 0)
>         {
>             continue;
>         }
> ```

Would it be better to throw an exception?

---

> ```
>         else if (itemSize == 1)
>         {
>             items[i] = response[index];
>         }
> ```

That's a bug waiting to happen in the future when you add support for `sbyte`.

---

> ```
>         {
>             var method = typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod($"To{itemType.Name}");
>             var returned = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { response, index });
>             items[i] = Convert.ChangeType(returned, itemType);
>         }
> ```

Ugh. I would much rather use T4 to generate the entire method and get rid of the reflection. That would probably also eliminate the need for `Sizeof`.

---

If you're using a recent .Net (e.g. .Net Core 2.1) then I think some combination of `Span<T>` and `Memory<T>` will do what you want. Over the past year or so, Microsoft has done a lot of work on C# features for byte-level memory manipulation. You can probably create a `struct` for the contents of the packet and coerce the `byte[]` into your struct with one or two lines of code.

Comment: @sebpinsky type.TypeCode can be used as an alternative for nameof(Type)

Comment: @dfhwze, (a) I don't think sebpinsky will get that notification; (b) `nameof(Type)` gives `"Type"`; (c) reviews of OP's code belong in an answer, not in comments on someone else's answer.

Comment: (b) was meant as pseudo-code, but could be confusing nevertheless (c) I have no idea how I ended up commenting the wrong section (brainfart I guess) + I will formulate an answer rather than commenting the next time

Comment: 1. I'd like to be consistent. I'd tried doing 'nameof(byte)' and 'nameof(Int8)' (which doesn't exist. Just realised it'll be 'nameof(Byte)'.

2. I'd like to use 'params Type[]' as the argument, but just suggesting this without a full call signature and any suggestion of how to implement the method is not helpful.

3. Agreed that exceptions and an exhaustive list of types would be better but as StackExchange ask, I've added a shortened version of the code.

4. Any suggestions of how to actually use T4 here again, or are you going to just keep me guessing?

Comment: I don't think T4 is the answer here, then you just have one more step in the pipeline for little to no benefit. Seems like a premature optimization to me.

Comment: @reggaeguitar, I see it more as using the right tool for the job. Reflection should be a last resort, not (just) because it's slow but because it moves errors from compile-time to runtime. That proposal also eliminates a large class of potential bugs in `Sizeof` while allowing easy extension to the full range of fixed width types. (Of course, it's important to note that the last paragraph renders the rest of the answer academic: I expect that all of the previous points will be things to take into account in the future rather than direct changes to make to the code).

Comment: @PeterTaylor That makes sense, I stand corrected. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 3):

If you determine the valid types to handle in code as it seems from your method, I would do it more rigidly than by using Reflection. There is no meaning in determining the byte length by "hand" and then afterwards call a method by Reflection relying on consistency in names (not to mention possible types with the same byte length).

Why not try something plain and simple like:

```
private void ConvertArray(byte[] response, ref object[] items)
{
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(response))
  using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
  {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
      var itemType = items[i].GetType();
      int itemSize = 0;

      switch (itemType.Name)
      {
        case nameof(Byte):
          items[i] = reader.ReadByte();
          itemSize = sizeof(byte);
          break;
        case nameof(UInt16):
          items[i] = reader.ReadUInt16();
          itemSize = sizeof(ushort);
          break;
        case nameof(UInt32):
          items[i] = reader.ReadUInt32();
          itemSize = sizeof(uint);
          break;
      }

      index += itemSize;
    }
  }
}
```

---

As dfhwze comments using the type code for primitives is even more stringent:

```
private void ConvertArray(byte[] response, ref object[] items)
{
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(response))
  using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
      var itemType = items[i].GetType();

      switch (Type.GetTypeCode(itemType))
      {
        case TypeCode.Byte:
          items[i] = reader.ReadByte();
          break;
        case TypeCode.UInt16:
          items[i] = reader.ReadUInt16();
          break;
        case TypeCode.UInt32:
          items[i] = reader.ReadUInt32();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As sebpinski points out in the comment the `index` and `itemSize` is unecessary in this approach.

Comment: Consider using itemType.TypeCode for primitive types. And +1 because I would also go the streamreader direction.

Comment: @dfhwze: good idea! - I'll update

Comment: @HenrikHansen I really like your suggestion here. The only problem now is the reassigning back to the original items. I don't need the' index' and 'itemSize' anymore with this implementation.

Comment: @sebpinski: Oh my! I didn't see that. What do you mean by 'reassigning back to the original items' ?

Comment: @HenrikHansen apologies, I wrote that comment not knowing that someone had reverted one of my edits to the question, so the reassigning was removed. I should have updated it again citing you.

Comment: @sebpinski: OK, but to be strict in respect to the rules on this site, you're not allowed to change the original question when answers have been posted. But you can always post a self-answer.

Comment: @HenrikHansen Apologies, I simply realised that I'd forgotten to include part of the original code, so added it. Frankly the original question wouldn't have worked without it. I won't update the question again now, as I didn't realise this was a rule in this community.